# Issues with boolean value functionality

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean

I have a Boolean column in one of the database table called "status" that i would like to use to control the status of the content being submitted by users, i've set its type to TINYINT and the default value for it is '0' and am using this snippet to apply functionality to the content

```
$status = '';

if ($row_userDetails['status'] == FALSE) {

 $status = 'Not Approved';
}
else {

$status = 'Approved';
}
```

`var_dump($row_userDetails['status'])` results are string(0) "0"
And then after i will use the status to display or not to display the content if approved or not respectively.

But my problem is, i can't seem to get a `TRUE` value i.e "`Approved`" when i `echo $status`, i only get the `FALSE` value i.e "`Not Approved`". Please help me out on this

Comment: Do a `var_dump($$row_userDetails)` and post the results here.

Comment: if db value 0,1 then use 0 or 1 for match

Comment: `var_dump($row_userDetails['status']) is showing string(1) "0" incrementing the value for "0" depending on the number content in the table

Comment: i tried changing the FALSE value to 0 but no positive results @ rakesh sharma

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing a discrepancy due to type-juggling.

It is 99% likely that `$row_userDetails['status']` is providing a `(string) 'FALSE'`

^^ If this is true then use: `if($row_userDetails['status'] === 'FALSE')` <-- notice the single quotes denoting a string value

The proper way to figure out what type you are working with is to use:

```
echo gettype($row_userDetails['status']);`
```

and it will display either `boolean`, `integer`, `double`, `string`, `array`, `object`, `resource`, or `NULL` as referenced **[here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php)**